# DynamicParam not working when prompt for input

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to get my powershell script to prompt for input, but still use a dynamicparam.  If I pass the parameters through the command line (Example: `DeployBuild "DEV02" "ClientPortal" "a" "b"`) , then the below code works fine, and I get prompted for the dynamic param.  If I chose not to pass the parameters via command line (Example: `DeployBuild`), and instead let the script prompt for input, the dynamic parameter quits working.  Does anyone have an idea why this is not working?

```
Function DeployBuild {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
            [ValidateSet("DEV01","DEV02","PEDEV01","QA01","QA02","UAT","PERF01","PROD")]
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
            [String]$environment,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
            [ValidateSet("AuthenticationService","ClientPortal")]
            [String]$application,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=3)]
            [String]$buildName,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=4)]
            [String]$buildNumber
    )


    DynamicParam{
        if ($environment -eq "DEV02"){
            #create a new ParameterAttribute Object              
            $buildVersionAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute               

            $buildVersionAttribute.Position = 5           
            $buildVersionAttribute.Mandatory = $true              


            #create an attributecollection object for the attribute just created.              
            $attributeCollection = new-object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]               

            #add our custom attribute              
            $attributeCollection.Add($buildVersionAttribute)               

            #add our paramater specifying the attribute collection              
            $buildVersionParam = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter('buildVersion', [double], $attributeCollection)               

            #expose the name of our parameter              
            $paramDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary             
            $paramDictionary.Add('buildVersion', $buildVersionParam)              

            return $paramDictionary
        }
    }

    End{
        Write-Host $environment
        Write-Host $application
        Write-Host $buildName
        Write-Host $buildNumber
        Write-Host $PSBoundParameters.buildVersion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this is really old so you probably don't need it anymore, but I'm pretty sure the reason this is happening is because of the conditional in the `DynamicParam` block that looks to see what the value of `$environment` is.

When the `DynamicParam` block is evaluated, `$environment` is blank, so the parameter is never added.

You can demonstrate this for yourself like this:

```
DynamicParam {
    Write-Verbose "DynamicParam here, environment is: '$environment'" -Verbose
    # ... rest of code here
}
```

Now run `DeployBuild` with no parameters and you'll see exactly when the block is being evaluated.